# Implementing boolean function using OR-NAND and NOR-OR

Tags: boolean-algebra, karnaugh-map

This is the boolean function: `F(A,B,C,D) = Σ (0,4,8,9,10,11,12,14)` and so after using a K-map to minimize it, I came out with `F(A,B,C,D) = C'D' + AB' + AD'`. Now the other two parts of the problem were representing it with AND-NOR gates and NAND-AND gates which I knew how to do. How do I do it with OR-NAND gates and NOR-OR gates?

Do I simply look for 0's in the karnaugh map and write a minimized boolean expression for 0's and then negate it? I'm very much confused by how to do this with OR and NAND gates. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the distributive properties of NOT,

C'D' + AB' + AD' = (C+D)' + (A'+B)' + (A'+D)'

C'D' + AB' + AD' = ((C+D)(A'+B)(A'+D))'

The inner parentheses use OR gates and the outer is a NAND

Comment: Perfect. Looks like I was making it more complicated than it needed to be. Do you have any ideas about NOR-OR?

Comment: yup, just use the end of the first step above (C+D)' is a NOR, (A'+B)' is another, and (A'+D)' is the third.  Then just OR them together.